# cat a file to show the 1st line and the grep queried value

Tags: shell-script

I have this following structure in file.txt

```
NTL|OPC|RN1|CNL|NUE|NUF|TPB|EIP
11212455464       |16384|55320|     |2799819E405       |                  |2|                                                  
32545687784       |16384|55320|     |1194155B581       |                  |2|                                                  
54565487788       |16384|55321|     |8599132D051       |                  |2|                                                  
23154688789       |4013|55115|11529|163624D585        |16D7620595        |1| 
...
```

and I want this result (the title plus the queried value)

```
NTL|OPC|RN1|CNL|NUE|NUF|TPB|EIP
23154688789       |4013|55115|11529|163624D585        |16D7620595        |1|
```

I tried something like this

```
head -1 file.txt | grep 23154688789
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `sed` instead, you can have it print line 1 and any line that matches like

```
sed -n -e '1p;/23154688789/p' file.txt
```

`-n` will tell it not to print output unless directed to, `1p` says print line 1 and `/23154688789/p` prints any line that matches that pattern

Answer (score 1):

In your code replace '|' with ';'
head gives you first line and piping it into grep makes grep search only in first line. You need something like this:

```
head -n 1 file.txt ; grep 23154688789 file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` command will allow this. Here we output the line if the Record Number (`NR`) is 1 or we get a match on the first field:

```
awk -v id=23154688789 'NR==1 || $1==id'
```

Result

```
NTL|OPC|RN1|CNL|NUE|NUF|TPB|EIP
23154688789       |4013|55115|11529|163624D585        |16D7620595        |1|
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *only* line starting with "NTL" will be the header line, a single `grep` can be used to achieve this.

```
$ grep -E '^NTL|23154688789' file.txt
NTL|OPC|RN1|CNL|NUE|NUF|TPB|EIP
23154688789 |4013|55115|11529|163624D585 |16D7620595 |1| . . .
$
```